# How can I read this kanji (Image attached)

Tags: kanji, handwriting

[image]

That's the Kanji in question.

I'm trying to learn Japanese character's writing and reading (with manga) and got stuck with this one, I've tried doing a search by radicals (jisho) and from a list of kanji by strokes (wikipedia) and couldn't find a reference.

Thanks for taking your time in reading my question!

Comment: Can you tell us what radicals you identify in this character?

Comment: I really got confused so I will tell you the ones I think there are: a nabebuta( ⼇), a ni (⼆) and a kuchi (⼝) for the left side. A juu (⼗), a ichi (⼀) and a kuchi (⼝) for the right side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is 話, made of 言＋舌.

Judging by the discussion under the other answer, you were unable to recognize 言 because of the variation in the direction of the first stroke.  Take a look at the following examples:

[image: 言]

These are examples of different ways to hand-write 言, taken from the official [常用漢字表](http://kokugo.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/joho/kijun/naikaku/pdf/joyokanjihyo_20101130.pdf).  You can find other examples of variation in this document, and I'd recommend taking a couple minutes to look through it to see if there are any other variations you're unfamiliar with.

As with many characters, there is not just *one* way to write 言, but several variations.  Once you're used to them, they'll all look like the same thing to you.

Answer (score 1):

It's this one

### [話](http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MMJ%E8%A9%B1)

Found from the kanji dictionary search at http://www.edrdg.org/

Comment: Sadly, it isn't mate, notice the left side of the kanji, that is a iu (⾔) radical, not the same from the one I shared.

Comment: @PolHayabusa The kanji in your image is simply a handwritten version of 話. Have a look at the [jisho.org page for this kanji](http://jisho.org/search/%E8%A9%B1%20%23kanji) which shows both the printed and handwritten version on the same page.

Comment: God, I even wanted to search for that possibility, but since I couldnt recognize the radicals properly I missed it. Thank you very much.